# Why is there no time delay in photo electric effect?

Tags: photons, wave-particle-duality, photoelectric-effect

Can someone explain to me (in simple words) why there is no time delay between photon absorption and photoelectric emission?

Comment: How do you conclude that there is no time delay?

Comment: Not zero -  Wikipedia, *The time lag between the incidence of radiation and the emission of a photoelectron is very small, less than 10^−9 second.*

Comment: @Farcher It's a shame they don't cite that, because I'd love to see whether that's empirical or computed with e.g. FGR.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I personally feel good question based on what's usually reached at schools

Comment: @Farcher "In quantum mechanics, the photoelectric effect is viewed as
a single collisional event and no time delay is predicted." source: [this thing written in comic sans by an oxford prof](http://vallance.chem.ox.ac.uk/pdfs/PhotoelectricEffect.pdf)

Comment: @AdilMohammed quantum mechanics does predict a time delay because the wavefunctions of the photon and electron evolve with time and the interaction takes a non-zero time. I suspect what the author of that article means is that the time is so small as to be approximately zero and this is different from the classical situation where the time can be much longer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unaware of any experimental results measuring this in solids, but for the case of isolated gas-phase atoms,

- there *is* a time delay between the photon absorption and the emission of the photoelectron,
- it has already been measured (cf. e.g. the papers in [this search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=delays+in+photoionization)), and
- it is *very* small.

How small? The comments to the question suggest that it is less than $10^{-9}\:\rm s$, and this is true but misleading $-$ experimental results and the accompanying theory show that it is typically in the range of a few to a few tens (potentially a few hundreds) of attoseconds, i.e. $10^{-16}$-$10^{-18}\:\rm s$.

It's possible that the same has been done for solids (in which case you would probably use a nanotip, though that comes with complications coming from plasmonic field enhancement at the tip) and I've missed it, but I would not expect the delay to be substantially bigger $-$ perhaps one or two orders of magnitude at most. There are massive problems in measuring this experimentally because you need a good timing reference, and this is particularly challenging in solids, but it's not an unreasonable thing to ask; if it hasn't already been measured then it's definitely on the plate of several cutting-edge research groups at this stage.

Comment: Would this not depend on the photon energy? I don’t see how the electron could absorb the energy in a substantially shorter time than the oscillation period, unless there is large uncertainty in the emission energy. Given that this energy uncertainty empirically seems much less than the energy itself (from my shallow understanding of ARPES data, at least), I would presume that this implies an absorption time of at least a few oscillations (which, for visible light and a low work function material, could take as long as 10 fs).